# How to get all parent processes and all subprocesses with `pstree`

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Command `pstree PID` can show all subprocess information of the process specified by `PID`. However, I also want to know all parent process information of the process `PID`, how can I get it?

An example:

```
init
|- parent_process
|    `- current_process
|       |- subprocess_1
|       `- subprocess_2
`- other_process
```

What I want is when I run `pstree current_process_pid`, I want to get below output:

```
init
`- parent_process
    `- current_process
       |- subprocess_1
       `- subprocess_2
```

When I run `pstree subprocess_1_pid`, it will output:

```
init
`- parent_process
    `- current_process
       `- subprocess_1
```

Comment: Note: Using -l option of the pstree/ps commands shows long lines with command line arguments of the process. Helpful when you want to trace command line arguments for each process and see which command/script gets triggered (for example figure out which backend scripts are run for a web UI operation).

Answer (score 24):

```
# With my psmisc 22.20:
pstree -p -s PID
```

Maybe if with ps -ef:

```
awk -vPID=$1 '
function getParent ( pid ) {
    if (pid == "" || pid == "0") return;
    while ("ps -ef | grep "pid | getline) {
        if ($2 == pid) {
            print $8"("$2") Called By "$3;
            getParent($3);
            break;
        }
    }
    close ("ps -ef")
}

BEGIN { getParent(PID) }
'
```

This is ugly assuming ps output column and order. Actually one single run of ps -ef contains all info needed.
This don't worth the time, I still recommend updating psmisc, it won't hurt.

EDIT: A mimic using single run ps -ef:

```
ps -ef | awk -vPID=$1 '
function getpp ( pid, pcmd, proc ) {
    for ( p in pcmd ) {
        if (p == pid) {
            getpp(proc[p], pcmd, proc);
            if (pid != PID) printf("%s(%s)───", pcmd[pid], pid);
        }
    }
}

NR > 1 {
    # pid=>cmd
    pcmd[$2] = $8;
    # pid=>Parent
    pproc[$2] = $3;
}

END {
    getpp(PID, pcmd, pproc);
    printf "\n";
    system("pstree -p "PID);
}'
```

Comment: `-s` option not supported by my `pstree` which installed by `psmisc-22.2-7.el5_6.2`

Comment: As a mnemonic I remember the args as `laps` as in `pstree -laps <pid>` to get the branch with additional information.

Comment: @MeaCulpa hmm for me `pstree -p -s PID` doesn't work, but `pstree -s -p PID` works... on mac

Answer (score 10):

I found `laps` options mentioned by @haridsv (`pstree -laps <pid>`) being a solution. It was a bit verbose for me though, so I'd stick to a shorter `aps` output.

To get the process tree of the current process (its ID is `$$` in Bash):

```
pstree -aps $$
```

That prints the process tree like this:

```
systemd,1
  └─kitty,86739
      └─bash,86742
          └─pstree,86904 -aps 86742
```

Comment: (using `pstree (PSmisc) 23.4`) for maximum verbosity: `pstree -calpsSngtuZ $SOME_PID`