# Get Linux Apt-Get background process into the terminal without any other Application

Tags: linux, terminal, process

Heey, I wanted to install something on my Linux system using the `Apt-Get` function. However, the installation is frozen in a selection menu. Then I closed the terminal to run the installation again. However, an error occurred during the restart:

> Couldn't get exclusive access to the / var / lib / dpkg /
> lock-frontend lock file. This is held by process 65321 (apt-get). N:
> Note that removing the lock file is not a solution and can destroy
> your system. E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/ var / lib
> / dpkg / lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Now my question is whether I can pull this process out of the background again. It would be best without another program, since it is probably rather difficult to install without the `apt-get-installer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dominik has already mentioned, it is not possible to stop the background processes without downloading one of the apps. Most of them have to be downloaded with Composer with the exception of Gnu Screen on Github: https://github.com/shyouhei/screen

Comment: It is possible to stop the background processes, but you are not able to gain control over them ...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible, to access another process without using virtual screens like GNU screen or tmux.

I would first check these logs:

```
/var/log/apt/history.log
/var/log/apt/term.log
/var/log/dpkg.log
```

If apt isn't doing anything, you could get the PID of the APT process and try to kill it. Or even better: find out if there are any subprocesses of APT (take a look at `pstree`), maybe you'll find one waiting for input and kill that process.

After that, try to reinstall your package.

More info:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/how-can-i-switch-between-ttys-without-using-screen
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/222587/how-to-check-apt-get-upgrade-status-after-losing-ssh-connection
- [how to get all parent processes and all subprocesses by `pstree`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852023/how-to-get-all-parent-processes-and-all-subprocesses-by-pstree)